# How to access 10 largest numbers inside my priority queue

Tags: c++, list, priority-queue

Assuming I have 30 random numbers inside my priority queue, how do I access only a specific number of largest values after I sort them. For example I need to print the top 10 largest numbers inside my priority queue

Comment: Seems like an odd priority queue, if youre going to ignore FIFO on whatever you're prioritising and pull the highest 33% values from it. Why aren't you making the number the priority?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question, but you can just pull 10 numbers from the priority queue and they will be sorted in descending order (assuming it's a max-queue).

Comment: I have edited the question to change "call" to "access".  Is that correct? (feel free to fix if not).  The problem is that you can't "call" a number in C++, you can only call functions (and things like functions).

Comment: @CaiusJard how do i do that? any codes to help

Comment: @MartinBonner actually i have to store them inside a list first, and then access them by using a priority queue in order to get top 10 largest numbers. So any idea how to do it?

Comment: sure @MartinBonner thanks for the edit my bad anyway

Comment: @CaiusJard please help. i have fixed the question

Comment: @MartinBonner i have fixed the question

Comment: @MartinBonner i have fixed the question

Comment: `/*remove duplicate numbers */
mylist.unique();` It is actually not accurate, they still may have duplicate in list: `std::list::unique` only remove adjacent duplicates.

Comment: @Jarod42 so how do i actually remove duplicates?

Comment: full sort allows to call unique to remove duplicates.

Comment: how to do full sort? @Jarod42

Comment: a precise coding/syntax would help @Jarod42

Comment: `mylist.sort(); mylist.unique();`.

Comment: But then `priority_queue` is mostly useless.

Comment: wow i just know that. may i know the reason(s) why if use unique wont work? @Jarod42

Comment: unique removes **adjacent** duplicated, so for `{1, 2, 1}`, nothing is removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you push all random numbers into the queue: ok. Then you access the top numbers, and while you go, remove them from list:

```
const int desired_numbers = 10;
for(int i=0; i<desired_numbers; i++)
{
    int t = mypq_decreasing.top();
    mypq_decreasing.pop();

    mylist.remove(t); //remove from original list
}
```

After this, both the queue and the list contain all random numbers, but ten (because after every access to top, you popped the top out of the queue and removed the element from list).

Comment: no actually i need to get the 10 numbers from the priority queue, not from another list

Comment: Once you access the top of the queue, you got the largest int back. To access the next, you have to pop (i.e. remove from queue) the top you just read, and read top again. Then pop, then read, and so on. In the end, you can't read elements you removed from queue, that's why I suggested to save them in a list while you read-and-pop them.

Comment: but let say my question is this: Using priority queue, take out and print the top 10 largest number in the list.
Print the list again after the five numbers have been taken out. how do i print the same list again, but without the 10 numbers that have been separated? it will print all elements right?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, you want to access the X largest numbers from a list of size 30 through a priority queue, you can do it like this.

```
template<typename T>
struct my_less;
//Specialization in order to dereference a pointer before doing the comparison
template<typename T>
struct my_less<T*>
{
  void operator (T* lhs, T* rhs){
   return (*lhs)<(*rhs);
  }
}
using lookupPriorityQueue=std::priority_queue<int*,std::vector<int*>,my_less<int*>>;
lookupPriorityQueue p;
for(auto& element: your_list_of_ints)
{
   p.push(&element);
}
for(auto i=0;i!=10;++i,p.pop())
{
  std::cout<<*(p.top())<<"\n";
}
```

Using this approach, you don't have to copy everything to the priority_queue in order to find out the top X elements. 
However you should be really careful because we are storing pointers to elements and if the priority_queue outlives the list we will be accessing  invalid memory

Comment: how do i use your codes/parts of you codes with my original codes? i am sorry im a beginner

Comment: how do i use your codes/parts of you codes with my original codes? i am sorry im a beginner

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't need `priority_queue`, just use algorithm:

```
std::vector<int> numbers /*= */;

std::partial_sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.begin() + 10, std::greater<>());

for (std::size_t i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
{
    std::cout << numbers[i] << " ";
}
```

Comment: i am sorry but my task is: Create a list of size 30, and fill it up with random numbers in the range of 0 to 99. Remove all duplicate numbers, and print out the list of integers generated.
Using priority queue, take out and print the top 10 largest number in the list.
Print the list again after the five numbers have been taken out.